# TestNG - Custom reporter listener issue with failsafe plugin

Tags: testng, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have a project in which I used maven `fail-safe` plugin to run the integration tests. I am using the `Maven + TestNG` framework combination. For the project purpose, earlier I have modified the TestNG's default ***XML Report*** to customize the project needs.

I implemented the above said requirement in a *CustomReporter* class which extends the TestNG's `IReporter`interface. Earlier I used `surefire` plugin to run these test methods and adding the `listener mechanism` in the surefire plugin works as expected.

Now for certain project needs, I need to migrate to failsafe plugin. So I bypassed the `test` phase execution of `surefire` by configuring the POM file.

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then I have added the failsafe configuration in the POM file as below;

```
 <

plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>fail-safe-myplug</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <skip>false</skip> 
                    <properties>                
                        <property>  
                        <name>listener</name>
                            <value>com.CustomXmlReport</value>
                                </property>
                            </properties>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                            </includes>                     
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>
```

With this new POM, integration test invocation with `failsafe` plugin is failing. Following are the log;

```
Running com.myPack.AppTest
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.`surefire`.testng.conf.TestNGMapConfigurator@ab50cd
org.apache.maven.surefire.util.`SurefireReflectionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:103)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:74)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Expected static method org.testng.reporters.XMLReporterConfig.getTimestampFormat()Ljava/lang/String;
    at com.myPack.CustomSuiteResultWriter.getTestResultAttributes(CustomSuiteResultWriter.java:175)
    at com.myPack.CustomSuiteResultWriter.addTestResult(CustomSuiteResultWriter.java:138)
    at com.myPack.CustomSuiteResultWriter.addTestResults(CustomSuiteResultWriter.java:117)
    at com.myPack.CustomSuiteResultWriter.writeAllToBuffer(CustomSuiteResultWriter.java:76)
    at com.myPack.CustomSuiteResultWriter.writeSuiteResult(CustomSuiteResultWriter.java:56)
    at com.myPack.CustomXmlReportGenerator.writeSuiteToBuffer(CustomXmlReportGenerator.java:102)
    at com.myPack.CustomXmlReportGenerator.writeSuite(CustomXmlReportGenerator.java:65)
    at com.myPack.CustomXmlReportGenerator.generateReport(CustomXmlReportGenerator.java:42)
    at org.testng.TestNG.generateReports(TestNG.java:780)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:766)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:112)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:115)
    ... 9 more
```

Eventhough I am using `failsafe` plugin in the `integration-test` phase, I am getting the exception

*Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.`surefire`.testng.conf.TestNGMapConfigurator@ab50cd
    org.apache.maven.surefire.util.`SurefireReflectionException*

How to resolve this issue ?

Note : When I tried to execute the tests using `surefire` plugin, the **listener mechanishm** works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the issue is, the compatibility with `Failsafe` and `TestNG` versions. I was using `TestNG 5.9v` with `failsafe plugin 2.12v`. This is the root cause for the issue.

I downgraded the `Failsafe` version to `2.5v` and the issue got resolved.

Thanks to google groups for guiding me to think in version perspective. 
http://groups.google.com/group/testng-users/browse_thread/thread/b54417e5a61c5c62

Comment: I am getting the same issue, unresolved. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48657869/running-maven-integration-test-inside-docker-container 

Any help?