# Running maven integration test inside docker container

Tags: java, maven, dockerfile

I am using dockerfile-maven plugin to move my jar file inside docker container before running integration testing. But mvn verify command builds the images and run integration test, as a result test fails. Can someone help me run the docker images before running integration test. So that I can ping to service running inside docker container from my integration test file.

Below is my integration test file.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.*;
import static org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers.*;
import org.junit.Assert.*;
import com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoDriver;
import io.airlift.log.Logger;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

class IntegrationTestIT {

@Test
public void checkForQueryInFile() {

    System.out.println("This test method should be run");
    String url = "jdbc:presto://localhost:8889/jmx/default";

    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "jumbo", null);

        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        String file_path = "";
        String sql_string = "show schemas";

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql_string);
        File folder = new File("//jars");
        // Move this to constant class
        File[] files = folder.listFiles(); 

        for (File file:files) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                file_path = file.getAbsolutePath();
            }
        }
        File log_file = new File(file_path);
        final String scanner = new Scanner(log_file).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();;

        assertThat(scanner, containsString(sql_string));

    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    connection.close();

    } catch (IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    } catch(SQLException sqlException) {
        sqlException.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Test Report:

```
[INFO] Successfully built rohitbarnwal7/presto_log_updated:0.0.1
[INFO] maven-failsafe-plugin:2.5:integration-test (default) @plugin
[INFO] Failsafe report directory: /Users/rohit/workspace/presto plugins/target/failsafe-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.833 sec <<< FAILURE!

Results :

Failed tests:
  checkForQueryInFile(IntegrationTestIT)

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Integration Test result from TestSuite.txt

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.559 sec <<< FAILURE!
checkForQueryInFile(IntegrationTestIT)  Time elapsed: 0.015 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper can not access a member of class IntegrationTestIT with modifiers "public"
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:102)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowCheckMemberAccess(AccessibleObject.java:296)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:288)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1191)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1116)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1024)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:62)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:350)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1021)
```

Comment: First suggestion upgrade the used maven-failsafe-plugin version....

Comment: Tried that as well then I downgraded it, owing to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003812/testng-custom-reporter-listener-issue-with-failsafe-plugin

Comment: @khmarbaise any further suggestion here. I have been looking to solution for a while without much of success.

Comment: Do you have an example project on Github or Bitbucket etc. ?

Comment: It's on private repository. I can share error logs and other required details.

Comment: Create some snippet like project from your original and remove everything confidential...otherwise it's hard to see the real issue...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164728/discussion-between-rohit-barnwal-and-khmarbaise).

Answer (score 2):

### Accessibility error message :

> java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper can not access a member of class IntegrationTestIT with modifiers "public"

You have to make your class public to run tests :

```
public class IntegrationTestIT {
...
```

### Sequencing issue :

If your integration tests are running in the `integration-test` phase, you can force the execution of the docker plugin during the `pre-integration-test` phase :

```
<execution>
    ...
    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
</execution>
```

Comment: Doesn't help. 

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.558 sec <<< FAILURE!
checkForQueryInFile(IntegrationTestIT)  Time elapsed: 0.033 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper can not access a member of class IntegrationTestIT with modifiers "public"

Comment: Error resolved, but docker didn't run after build was complete as a result test isn't passed. Test case was expecting presto server running on port 8889 of docker mapped to 8889 of host, hence throws this error:
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8889